# Im Using This Ajax inside the close function of Tiny Box

Tags: javascript

```
TINY.box.show({
    iframe : '.action
    width : ($(window).width() - 50),
    height : ($(window).height() - 80),
    fixed : false,
    maskid : 'bluemask',
    maskopacity : 100,
    closejs : function() {


          $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                async:false,
                url: "abc.action",
                data: ",
                success: function(msg){
                    document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML=msg;
                }
        }); 
    }
})
```

Comment: Please add some information about what you are trying to do and what is going wrong. Only adding a code snipped won't get you a good answer

Comment: I want to get a "DIV" refreshed once the tiny box get closed.

Comment: On second line `iframe : '.action` you are missing trailing `',`. It should be like `iframe : '.action',`

Comment: Its there and the execution is done but once the iframe closes I need to get a refresh inside the div I have given an Ajax inside the close function its not working